# Python nested for loop: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, loops

I am working with data pulled from a spreadsheet-like file. I am trying to find, for each "ligand", the item with the lowest corresponding "energy". To do this I'm trying to make a list of all the ligands I find in the file, and compare them to one another, using the index value to find the energy of each ligand, keeping the one with the lowest energy. However, the following loop is not working out for me. The program won't finish, it just keeps running until I cancel it manually. I'm assuming this is due to an error in the structure of my loop.

```
for item in ligandList:
    for i in ligandList:
        if ligandList.index(item) != ligandList.index(i):
            if ( item == i ) :
                if float(lineList[ligandList.index(i)][42]) < float(lineList[ligandList.index(item)][42]):
                    lineList.remove(ligandList.index(item))
                else:
                    lineList.remove(ligandList.index(i))
```

As you can see, I've created a separate ligandList containing the ligands, and am using the current index of that list to access the energy values in the lineList.

Does anyone know why  this isn't working?

Comment: indentation for the first two lines are wwrong

Comment: Instead of `for item in` and `.index(item)` consider using `for index, item in enumerate(ligandList)`.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't in the original code, just an error in transfer.

Comment: Assuming your indentation is actually right (because it wouldn’t run otherwise), remember that `.remove` doesn’t remove by index. Also, use `enumerate()`, please; `.index` isn’t efficient. (And `i` is usually used to represent index.)

Comment: None of that should matter; what you've posted isn't an infinite loop. It should only run for len(ligandList) ** 2 iterations, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Why are you not just fetching the minimum from the list? The nested pairwise comparison will eventually end up doing that but it's going to take eons.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the minimum for each ligand, meaning if there are duplicate ligands, I only keep the one with the lowest energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to answer without some actual data to play with, but I hope this works, or at least leads you into the right direction:

```
for idx1, item1 in enumerate(ligandList):
    for idx2, item2 in enumerate(ligandList):
        if idx1 == idx2: continue
        if item1 != item2: continue
        if float(lineList[idx1][42]) < float(lineList[idx2][42]):
            del lineList [idx1]
        else:
            del lineList [idx2]
```

Comment: okay... any idea why i might be getting a "list index out of range" error with this?

Comment: Because `lineList` changes over the iterations. (It gets shorter)

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't remove from lineList, but assign a value to the affected cell that indicates "no to be considered".

Answer (score 1):

You look like you're trying to find the element in `ligandList` with the smallest value in index 42. Let's just do that....

```
min(ligandList, key=lambda x: float(x[42]))
```

If these "Ligands" are something you use regularly, STRONGLY consider writing a class wrapper for them, something like:

```
class Ligand(object):
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.attr_name = lst[index_of_attr] # for each attribute
        ... # for each attribute
        ... # etc etc
        self.energy = lst[42]
    def __str__(self):
        """This method defines what the class looks like if you call str() on
it, e.g. a call to print(Ligand) will show this function's return value."""
        return "A Ligand with energy {}".format(self.energy) # or w/e
    def transmogfiscate(self,other):
        pass # replace this with whatever Ligands do, if they do things...
```

In which case you can simply create a list of the Ligands:

```
ligands = [Ligand(ligand) for ligand in ligandList]
```

and return the object with the smallest energy:

```
lil_ligand = min(ligands, key=lambda ligand: ligand.energy)
```

As a huge aside, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) encourages the use of the `lowercase` naming convention for variables, rather than `mixedCase` as many languages use.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a really inefficient way of doing things. Lots of `index` calls. It might just feel infinite because it’s slow.

Zip your related things together:

```
l = zip(ligandList, lineList)
```

Sort them by “ligand” and “energy”:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1][42]))
```

Grab the first (lowest) “energy” for each:

```
l = ((lig, lin[1].next()[1]) for lig, lin in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Yay.

```
result = ((lig, lin[1].next()[1]) for lig, lin in itertools.groupby(
    sorted(zip(ligandList, lineList), key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1][42])),
    lambda t: t[0]
))
```

It would probably look more flattering if you made `lineList` contain classes of some kind.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/oXKabXdH)